# Starting Transitions and Animations With Area Graph in D3.JS

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, d3.js

I want to have the area graph "draw" itself at the start of the program from left to right.  I already have one line in my graph doing this, however I cannot get the area under the line to correctly animate, or "draw" itself when the page first boots up.  Currently, this is what I have for my area.

```
var area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(function(d) {return xScale(d.date); })
    .y0(line_chart_height)
    .y1(function(d) {return yScale(d.close); });

line_chart.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr("d", area)
```

I can get the area up there fine and draw the line fine, but I can't make it so that when the page first loads the area will essentially "draw" itself from left to right like a line would in this example, EXCEPT from left to right, not right to left.

Any help is appreciated, I've tried using the following and it hans't worked for me.

```
.datum(data)
.transition().duration(2500)
.attr("d", area)
```

Thanks in advance,
Sam

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider using an [svg clipPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath), i.e.:

```
svg.append("clipPath")
    .attr("id", "rectClip")
  .append("rect")
    .attr("width", 0)
    .attr("height", height);
```

Then, you can simulate the drawing of the items by transitioning the clipping path on page load:

```
d3.select("#rectClip rect")
  .transition().duration(3000)
    .attr("width", width);
```

Here is an example jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qAHC2/688/.

Comment: That is pretty. Nice work! Are there other attributes that take a `url(#id)` value? It seems like it is short hand for `document.getElementById`, but it only works within svg?

Comment: Very good idea! Will work for my other graphs as well.  Thanks.