# D3 area graph animation

Tags: angularjs, animation, d3.js, svg, graph

I have an area graph ( see js fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/o7df3tyn/ )  I want to animate this area graph. I tried the approach in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23189358/starting-transitions-and-animations-with-area-graph-in-d3-js)
question , but this doesnt seem to help because I have more line graphs in the the same svg element

```
var numberOfDays = 30;

 var vis = d3.select('#visualisation'),
        WIDTH = 1000,
        HEIGHT = 400,
        MARGINS = {
          top: 20,
          right: 20,
          bottom: 20,
          left: 50
        };

  var drawArea = function (data) {
        var areaData = data;
        // var areaData = data.data;
        var  xRange = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([0, numberOfDays + 1]),
          yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([_.min(areaData), _.max(areaData)]);

        var area = d3.svg.area()
            .interpolate("monotone")
            .x(function(d) {
              return xRange(areaData.indexOf(d));
            })
            .y0(HEIGHT)
            .y1(function(d) {
              return yRange(d);
            });

        var path = vis.append("path")
        .datum(areaData)
        .attr("fill", 'lightgrey')
        .attr("d", area);
      };
 var data = [1088,978,1282,755,908,1341,616,727,1281,247,1188,11204,556,15967,623,681,605,7267,4719,9665,5719,5907,3520,1286,1368,3243,2451,1674,1357,7414,2726]     
 drawArea(data);
```

So I cant use the curtain approach.
I want to animate the area from bottom.
Any ideas / explanations ?

Just in case anyone else stuck in the same problem, @thatOneGuy  nailed the exact problem. My updated fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/sahils/o7df3tyn/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is okay but this doesn't animate the graph.

Here is how I would do it.

I would add an animation tween to the path so it tweens from 0 to the point on the path.

Something like so :

```
//create an array of 0's the same size as your current array :  

     var startData = areaData.map(function(datum) {
        return 0;
      });

//use this and tween between startData and data

 var path = vis.append("path")
    .datum(startdata1)
    .attr("fill", 'lightgrey')
    .attr("d", area)
    .transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .attrTween('d', function() {
      var interpolator = d3.interpolateArray(startData, areaData );
      return function(t) { 
      return area(interpolator(t)); 

      } 
    });
```

The reason why yours wasn't working was because of this line :

```
.x(function(d) {
      return xRange(areaData.indexOf(d));
    })
```

`d` at this point is a value between 0 and the current piece of data, so `areaData.indexOf(d)` will not work.

Just change this :

```
 .x(function(d,i) { 
      return xRange(i);
    })
```

This will increment along the x axis :)

Updated fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/o7df3tyn/17/

Comment: Thanks , a lot that solved it . Just curious. I am representing a plain integer ( actually it is number of days) So shouldnt xRange(index) be same as xRange(areaData.indexOf(d)).  I tried printing i in evry iteration . it prints as 1 2 3 4 .. as well . So I am a little confused about this. May be I am not getting how this area function is working. According to my understanding , it denotes each value to be plotted on xAxis, somilary d in y function denotes value on Y axis.

Comment: Your data is an array of integers, at at the moment you are just plotting it as they arrive in the array. So day 0, is the first, day 1, is the second and so on. So the best way to do this would be to use 'i' rather than what you have now which is using indexOf. As when you do the tween, you pass the values to the area function and it goes checks the areaData for your current value, which atm is inbetween 0 and the data value so it will never find it. To solve this just use 'i' which gives the same output

Comment: Got it .  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/DavidGuan/o7df3tyn/2/

```
vis.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "rectClip")
.append("rect")
  .attr("width", 0)
  .attr("height", HEIGHT);
```

You can have a try now.

**Remember add clip-path `attr` to the svg elements you want to hide**

In this case

```
var path = vis.append("path")
  .datum(areaData)
  .attr("fill", 'lightgrey')
  .attr("d", area)
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#rectClip)")
```

Update:
If we want to grow the area from bottom:

```
vis.append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "rectClip")
.append("rect")
  .attr("width", WIDTH)
  .attr("height", HEIGHT)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + HEIGHT + ")")

d3.select("#rectClip rect")
  .transition().duration(6000)
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 0 + ")")
```

Comment: This doesnt really solve my problem . I have to make the graph grow from bottom. That is where I am struggling. Having an overlay doesnt solve my problem( as in this case I can am gonna draw the graph, and then animate it out of the overlay.) I rather need to grow the graph out of the x axis.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o7df3tyn/3/ This is the updated fillde . Like I am transitioning my are graph from white to grey over a period of two seconds. But I need to grow the graph from zero to the graphs value.